# Create hint for my commands

Tags: macros, editors, auto-completion

I am creating a `.sty` file and I want it to be user friendly. Is there any way to create hints for my own commands such as I see it in Kile for standard LaTeX commands?

[image: hint in Kile]

I'd like to have a command that would look like that

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{#1}
```

and when I start typing `\myc`, it would show me

```
\mycommand{text}
```

Can it be done in `.sty` so it will show in any editor, or are those hints some kind of special setting for each editor?

Comment: I would feel almost certain that those are purely editor functions, having nothing to do with the underlying LaTeX.

Comment: For the record, AUCTeX can automatically parse the file and understand that `\mycommand` takes one mandatory argument.  You don't need to do anything more.

Comment: When I create the command in the document (`.tex` file) and compile it, then even Kile shows me `\mycommand{x}` while typing. The problem is that it does not show it when the command is in a `.sty` file. And that it shows `x` instead of a description (e.g. `text`).

Comment: As Steven said, it's an editor feature, independent from Latex. You'd have the same suggestions in Python, or any other programming language as long as the editor has the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments it depends on the editor. In Kile (I assume you use this editor form the comments) you can create an own `.cwl` file; see [Writing Own Completion Files](http://kile.sourceforge.net/Documentation/html/complete_own_files.html) in Kile’s manual.

For your command the file will just contain the line

```
\mycommand{text}
```

maybe with a comment.

```
# macros from mypkg.sty
\mycommand{text}
```

In the TeXstudio manual are some information about the CWL format: [4.13 Description of the cwl format](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION)

> Can it be done in .sty so it will show in any editor, or are those hints some kind of special setting for each editor?

As said this depends on the editor (some understand the CWL format) and you can’t define this in a `.sty` file. However if you publish a package you can add a matching `.cwl` file. In that case the user will have to install it manually (depending on where his editor looks for such files) or you can suggest these files to be included in the editors package. In that case you must contact the developers of the different editors.

Comment: Note that my understanding is that the `cwl` specification is created by and for TeXstudio. Not only whether, but how much of it other editors choose to support will vary. There's no standard for this stuff.

Comment: Yes, I use Kile, but the `.sty` file is also for my co-workers, who are working either on Windows or use different editors. The idea of a matching `.cwl` file is worth a try. Thanks.

Comment: @cfr: Ah … I thought it was kind of standard, because Kile uses them too.

Comment: I think Kile only supports a subset of what TeX Studio now supports. But I've never used TeX Studio - I'm just basing this on what somebody explained here in discussion.

Comment: Too bad that there is no way to include hints also in `.sty` file... Anyway this is the closest to the answer I was looking for.
And it works like a charm!
Unfortunately just copying the `.cwl` file to `~/.kde/share/apps/kile/complete/tex/` (as it is written in the 1st link) didn't work, I had to add it through "Settings > Configure Kile... > Complete".

Comment: @VáclavPavlík: Hm … I don't use Kile but if it doesn't work as said in the manual you may contact the developer(s) and report this as kind of bug (either in the docs or in the program itself) …

Answer (score 0):

Kile allows you to add these interactively. However, the interface does not work as well as it used to. Indeed, Kile is no longer able to find its own default `.cwl` files on my machines.

In the configuration dialogue, `LaTeX > General` offers a `Configure...` button at the top which is labelled `Configure LaTeX environments and commands`.

If you click this button, you get a dialogue with two tabs: one for environments and one for commands. These are grouped by function e.g. `Maths` or `Lists`. If you click a group, you can use the `Add` button at the bottom of the dialogue to add additional environments/commands. However, you can no longer add new groups (at least, I can't).

[image: screenshot: environment]

Here's a command:

[image: screenshot: command]

There are many frustrating features of this interface: inability to add new groups, inability to specify more than one optional and more than one mandatory argument, inability to specify macros requiring non-standard syntax etc. etc.

Possibly the `.cwl` file approach is, therefore, more useful. For simple cases, however, the GUI may be a useful technique.